# Hyphenation algorithm using Bloom filter

Tags: bloom-filter, hyphenation

A classical example of where Bloom filters shine is in [hyphenation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphenation_algorithm). It's even the example given in the [original paper on Bloom filters](https://uvammm.github.io/docs/bloom.pdf).

I don't understand how a Bloom filter would be used in a hyphenation algorithm.

A hyphenation algorithm is defined as something that takes an input word and gives back the possible ways that that word can be hyphenated.

Would the Bloom filter contain both `hyph-enation` and `hyphena-tion`, and client code would query the filter for `h-yphenation`, `hy-phenation`, `hyp-henation`, ...?

Here's what the original paper says:

> **Analysis of Hyphenation Sample Application**
>
> [...] Let us assume that there are about 500,000 words to be hyphenated by the program and that 450,000 of these words can be hyphenated by application of a few simple rules. The other 50,000 words require reference to a dictionary. It is reasonable to estimate that at least 19 bits would, on the average, be required to represent each of these 50,000 words using a conventional hash-coding method. If we assume that a time factor of T = 4 is acceptable, we find from eq. (9) that the hash area would be 2,000,000 bits in size. This might very well be too large for a practical core contained hash area. By using method 2 with an allowable error frequency of, say, P = 1/16, and using the smallest possible hash area by having T = 2, we see from eq. (22) that the problem can be solved with a hash area of less than 300,000 bits, a size which would very likely be suitable for a core hash area. With a choice for P of 1/16, an access would be required to the disk resident dictionary for approximately 50,000 + 450,000/16 ~ 78,000 of the 500,000 words to be hyphenated, i.e. for approximately 16 percent of the cases. This constitutes a reduction of 84 percent in the number of disk accesses from those required in a typical conventional approach using a completely disk resident hash area and dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case,

- the dictionary is stored on disk and contains all words with the correct hyphenation,
- the Bloom filter contains just keys that require special hyphenation, e.g. maybe `hyphenation` itself,
- the Bloom filter responds with "probably" or "no".

Then the algorithm to find the possible hyphenations of a word is:

```
word = "hyphenation"; (or some other word)
x = bloomFilter.probablyContains(word);
if (x == "probably") {
    lookupInDictionary(word).getHypenation();
} else {
    // x == "no" case
    useSimpleRuleBasedHypenation(word);
}
```

If the Bloom filter responds with "probably", then the algorithm would have to do a disk read in the dictionary.

The Bloom filter would respond with "probably" sometimes if there are in fact no special rules, in which case a disk I/O is done unnecessarily. But that's OK as long as that doesn't happen too often (false positive rate is low, e.g. 1/16).

The Bloom filter, as it doesn't have false negatives, would never respond with "no" for cases do *have* special hyphenation.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand this correctly, the Bloom filter itself has basically nothing to do with the actual hyphenation. It's simply used as a guard against performing an expensive operation unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes, this is how I understand this paragraph.